Russian movie about a Russian and American boy being kidnapped
Sometime in the 70s (I think) I watched a film, whose English title was "The Dear Boy". I think it was a Russian film.
The film was about two boys, a Russian and an American, being kidnapped. I forget the details, but the striking thing about the plot is that the Russian boy is very passive, but the American boy is much more aggressive, and fights back, and eventually the two of them do escape, largely due to the American's efforts, I think. The only other thing I can remember about the movie is towards the end, when one of the kidnappers, a woman, chases the pair on a motorcycle. I think the two boys were in a car during the chase scene, and possibly one of them was driving, but I'm not sure about that. I've also got the feeling that the chase was along a winding ravine around a mountain-side and the woman comes to a sticky end, but I doubt this is useful identifying information, in any case.
I've only sporadically thought about this movie over the years, but I'd be very impressed if this site can locate it for me. The evidence suggests this is a very obscure movie, and doing searches for the title "The Dear Boy" produces nothing.
NOTE: I think "The Dear Boy" was the kidnappers' approving term for the Russian boy, because he didn't resist, but I'm not sure about that.

It indeed exists. The movie is Dorogoy malchik from 1974. It's about 2 boys that are kidnapped and at some point are chased by a woman on a bike. It was directed by Aleksandr Stefanovich and was called The Dear Boy [as in 'expensive'] according to this poster or A Dear Boy according to this clip from the beginning:




Yes, from the clip, which is not terribly informative, however, it does seem likely this is the same film. Wow, official proof that Stack Exchange is mightier than Google. And it took less than an hour. Have you seen this film, or do you have supernatural search skills? I'm guessing the former, since the information you provide doesn't have any actual plot information. Note: I don't speak Russian, so I didn't understand a word of this clip - I'm assuming the language, including the voice-over singing, is in Russian.

I don't think I saw it, the footage didn't ring a bell. But it was relatively easy, I wish every ID question provided the actual title. Thanks for that. ;) Silly IMDb simply neglected to add the English title for whatever reason.

This looks like it might be the complete film, though without subtitles I would have no idea what it going on  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8in48bkO2mk . Maybe I'll try to find subtitles... Just curious what search terms you used. I didn't find anything doing Google searches.

I'll check my search history. EDIT: 70s + movie + dear boy

Clearly I need to improve my search skills. Thanks for the identification.

Ok, after having taken a look at the movie, this is definitely the same film, but it doesn't look the way I remember it at all. What terrible production values! I guess we have all been spoiled by Hollywood. And the two boys look much smaller than I remembered, but then I guess I was small too. :-) The final chase scene is pretty simple - the two boys just got into a car and took off. Looks like the American boy was driving. In case you are wondering why I am asking about a Russian film from the 70s, well, that is the kind of thing you watched if you were in India in the 70s. :-)

Sadly, the link that I referenced a couple of comments above as containing the complete film has been deleted. I guess I should have downloaded it while I had the chance. Then again, I never managed to find any subtitles for the film, and so never did understand what anyone was saying. :-(
